# How can retrieve current contact value on specific blockNumber?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan

Let's we've got the following contract's [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code) with some interval [variables](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L152-L157) like:

```
uint public feeMake;
uint public feeTake;
uint public feeRebate;
```

And corresponding [methods](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L181-L212) that allow to change their state like:

```
function changeFeeMake()
function changeFeeTake()
function changeFeeRebate()
```

Is it possible to retrieve these internal variable values on specific block or transaction number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this via web3 or within the smart contract code?

Comment: I guess via web3 would be better for me because I'm using nodejs

Comment: Look at the last answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/is-it-possible-to-access-storage-history-from-a-contract-in-solidity . You can specify the blocknumber for ``.call``